# Populate HTML template with $http response VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, http, promise, vue.js

I am new to VueJs and working on a small nutrition app. Currently, we want to make food recs based on certain nutrients.

The JS is as follows:

```js
        recommendFood: function() {
            this.recs = {};
            var _this = this;
            var getItem = function(ndbno,i,nid) {
                _this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/item?ndbno=' + ndbno).then(function(response) {
                        var someData = response.body;
                        var nutrients = someData.report.food.nutrients;
                        var item = someData.report.food;

                        item = this.addNutrientsToItem(item, nutrients);
                        this.recs[nid].push(item);
                });
            };

            for (var i=0; i<this.low_nutrients.length; i++) {
                this.low_nutrients[i].recs = [];
                this.recs[this.low_nutrients[i].id] = [];

                for (var k=0; k<this.low_nutrients[i].food_map.length; k++) {
                    var ndbno = this.low_nutrients[i].food_map[k];
                    getItem(ndbno,i,this.low_nutrients[i].id);
                }
            }
            console.log(this.recs)
        }
```

I want this.recs to be an object with attributes that are equivalent to a nutrient id (that we store). Each nutrient has a food_map array attached to the object that contains id's of foods that would be the recommendations. I need to send those id's (ndbno) to the http request to receive the object of that food recommendation (item).

The this.recs object actually populates correctly (despite there probably being a better way to write my code), however since it's waiting on the loop and promise, the html renders before the object is complete. Therefore, my html is blank. How can I display the recs on the html once they are updated on the promise result?

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div v-for="(nutrient, idx) in low_nutrients">
  <h2>{{nutrient.name}}</h2>
  <div>Recommended Foods:</div>
  <div>
    <div>Recs:</div>
    <div v-for="rec in recs[nutrient.id]">{{rec}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The desired object this.recs should look something like this (and it does show this in the console):

```js
this.recs = {
    291: [{},{},{}],
    316: [{},{},{}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this.recs` starts out empty. [Vue cannot detect property additions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), so you have to use [set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to tell it that new properties have been added (and to make those properties reactive).

Or you can re-assign a new object to `this.recs` rather than modifying its contents.

Comment: OK, I think that makes sense - instead of this.recs[nid].push(item), would I use: this.$set(this.recs,nid, item)? This is still giving me a blank template.  Roy J

Comment: My solution was to use the set. I did this.$set(this.recs,[this.low_nutrients[i].id],{}) w/in the first loop of the recommendFood fn to create blank objects within the recs object. Then, in getItem, I used this.$set(this.recs[nid],ndbno,item) to create the recs w/in each nutrient object.